# Implementation of Web service composition

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, composition, bpel

Can anyone tell me how to implement a web service composition scenario? I consider 4 composition steps(mentioned down below). Actually I have developed selection algorithm(step 2) and want to compare that with other related approaches. I want to know which technology or software packages should I use and How?

Services are WSDL-based(or SOAP-based) not RESTful

Web Service Composition Steps:
1)Web service discovery based on users' functional requirements
2)Select optimal services based on users' QoS(Quality of Service) Criteria and create execution plan
3)Generate composite service description
4)Execute composite service

Comment: please help! any comment?

Comment: No, what is your actual question? Since the question is tagged with bpel, it's already answered...

Comment: @vanto I know I have to use BPEL designer in Eclipse, I don't know how to put my own selection algorithm into the process designed and executed by BPEL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache ODE lists a couple of [tutorials](http://ode.apache.org/resource-services.html), which also include the usage of the Eclipse BPEL designer. The tutorials are rather old, so it may happen that the procedures have slightly changed. But perhaps they will still give you the needed advice. You may also check the WSO2 BPEL tutorials.

For a brief introduction into BPEL, you may find my [slidedeck](http://de.slideshare.net/vanto/web-services-orchestration-with-bpel-20-presentation) helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

For interested guys: These websites useful and can give you good practical view of web service composition

http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/~nguyen_n/home
http://langrid.org/services/en/exercises.html